# Could not load 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm trying to migrate from 2.0 to 3.1. I'm stuck at exception raising at configureservice method in startup.cs class

1. public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection
   services)
   {
   services.AddMvc(options =>
   {
   options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());

   ```
           IdentityRegistrar.Register(services);
           services.AddSignalR();

           //Configure Abp and Dependency Injection
           return services.AddAbp<AppLibraryBuilderWebFrontEndModule>(options =>
           {
               //Configure Log4Net logging
               options.IocManager.IocContainer.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(
                   f => f.UseAbpLog4Net().WithConfig("log4net.config")
               );
           });
       } }
   ```

Comment: Can someone please help me on this issue??

Comment: first question, do you have .net core 3.1 SDK on the machine?  which version of VS are you using?